# pyspark Parallelize a for loop in a recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-databricks

New to pyspark. I have a function that runs recursively in pyspark (databricks). I'm trying to parallelize at least the entry function so it doesn't take 10 days to run every day.   I'm just trying to calculate extended quantity of a given part.  But haven't been able to actually get anything working.  Any help or references would be great.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

def run_all():
    df = get_main()
    df_fg = spark.createDataFrame([{'fg_assembly_number': 'FG1'}, {'fg_assembly_number': 'FG2'}])
    # this is what I'm trying to parallelize
    for i, fg in enumerate(df_fg.collect()):
        fg = fg['fg_assembly_number']
        if not i:
            df_final = extend_parts(df, fg)
            df_final = df_final.withColumn('fg_assembly_number', lit(fg))
        else: 
            df_temp = extend_parts(df, fg)
            df_temp = df_temp.withColumn('fg_assembly_number', lit(fg))
            df_final = df_final.union(df_temp)
    return df_final

def run_all_parallel():
    df = get_main()
    df_fg = spark.createDataFrame([{'fg_assembly_number': 'FG1'}, {'fg_assembly_number': 'FG2'}])

    # I've tried
    df_final = df_fg.foreach(lambda fg: extend_parts(df, fg['fg_assembly_number']))
    # or 
    data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(df_fg.collect())
    df_final = data.map(lambda fg: extend_parts(df, fg['fg_assembly_number'])).reduce(lambda x,y: x.union(y))
    
    return df_final

def extend_parts(df_main, part:str, depth:int=0, current_quantity:float=1.0, current_chain = ''):
    """Gets the extended quantity and the depth of part number"""
    df_part = df_main.where(df_main.subassembly_number == part)
    df_part = df_part.withColumn("depth", lit(depth))
    df_part = df_part.withColumn("ext_quantity", df_part.quantity * current_quantity)   

    if depth == 0: 
        current_chain = part

    df_part = df_part.withColumn("chain", concat(lit(current_chain), lit('>'), df_part.child_number))

    df = df_part.alias('final') # doing this so I can union it later
    for row in df_part.select(['child_number', 'ext_quantity', 'chain']).collect(): 
        df_new = extend_parts(df_main, row['child_number'], depth+1, row['ext_quantity'], row['chain'])
        df = df.union(df_new)
    
    return df

def get_main():
    txt = "subassembly_number,child_number,quantity"
    txt += "\nFG1,S1,1"
    txt += "\nFG1,S2,2"
    txt += "\nFG1,S3,0.5"
    txt += "\nS1,S1.1,10"
    txt += "\nS1,S1.2,1"
    txt += "\nS1,S1.3,0"
    txt += "\nS2,S2.1,7"
    txt += "\nS2,S2.2,8"
    txt += "\nS2,S2.3,1"
    txt += "\nS3,S3.1,3"
    txt += "\nS3,S3.2,2"
    txt += "\nS1.1,S1.1.1,6"
    txt += "\nS1.1,S1.1.2,5"
    txt += "\nS1.2,S1.2.1,9"
    txt += "\nS1.2,S1.2.2,4"
    txt += "\nS1.3,S1.3.1,5"
    txt += "\nFG2,S1,2"

    data = io.StringIO(txt)
    pd_df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
    pd_df['quantity']=pd.to_numeric(pd_df['quantity'])
    return spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)


display(run_all_parallel())
```